# SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length (FF/Django/StartSSL/Windows)

Tags: django, ssl, apache

Question moved to Serverfault ( https://serverfault.com/questions/346125/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-ff-django-startssl-windows )

Feel free to delete this on if that's more appropriate (I don't know what the convention is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(That's a question for ServerFault more than StackOverflow.)

If I understand correctly, you've set up Django with SSL on port 8082 and without SSL on port 8081.

It's often not necessary to secure the communication between the Apache Httpd server and the server behind `ProxyPass`, from localhost to localhost. You could simply use `ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8081/`.

Alternatively, if you really want to use SSL/TLS for the communication to the backend (typically, if the server in the back is remote), you'd need to use `ProxyPass https://127.0.0.1:8082/` (`https`) and set the `SSLProxy*` directives (see [mod_proxy summary](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)).

Comment: Thanks the port things is much easier this way, I changed that. Doesn't affect the ssl_error_rx_record_too_long though :-/ Also I'll try move the question!